# how to standardize mixed date formats in the same column

Tags: r, date, dataframe

I have a data frame in which the data in one of the columns is currently "character" and I need to change it to "date" however the dates are mixed formats so I cannot just use as.Date(). There are also blank rows within the column. Here is a sample of the data

```
> head(FarmersMkt$StartDate,n = 50)
 [1] "June "       "January "    "05/01/2013 " "July "       "06/17/2013 "   "05/04/2013 " ""            "06/27/2013 "
 [9] "June "       ""            "06/29/2013 " "06/06/2013 " ""                "May "        ""            ""           
[17] "05/11/2013 " "01/01/2013 " ""            "June "       "June "           "06/06/2013 " ""            ""           
[25] ""            "04/20/2013 " ""            ""            "05/11/2013 "     ""            "01/01/2013 " "01/01/2013 "
[33] "06/06/2013 " "May "        "06/23/2013 " "01/01/2013 " "June 17, 2012 "        "June "       ""            ""           
[41] "06/06/2013 " ""            "May "        ""            ""                ""            "04/20/2013 " "01/01/2013 "
[49] "07/13/2013 " ""
```

The year for all should be 2013 and the date can be dummy data. How do I convert the data in this column to date format?

Comment: What do you want "June" converted to?

Comment: Good questions on Stack Overflow specify not only the data you have but also the expected output, so you should edit your question to say you only need month/year if that is the case. Are all the dates from 2013? Otherwise how do you know the year when the input in "June"?

Comment: We can use dummy date and year because I only really need the month but I need it in the same format as the others 06/06/2013

Answer (score 1):

Supposing you know about the year the observation was made, and you're comfortable with a mapping from "June" to something standardised, like "2013-06-01" (setting a month equal to the first day), then the approach I would take would be to generate two new columns, the first of which converts the "%m/%d/%Y" format to standard dates, and the second which converts the "%B" to standard dates. Then ifelse them together. So something like:

```
library(dplyr)

tt <- data.frame(date = c("June", "05/23/2013"))

tt %>% mutate(Date1 = as.Date(date, format = "%m/%d/%Y"),
          Date2 = as.Date(paste0("01-",date,"-2013"), format = "%d-%B-%Y"),
          newdate = ifelse(is.na(Date1), Date2, Date1) %>% as.Date(origin = "1970-01-01"))
```

Comment: This will return `NA` for 'June' if your Locale is not set to an English language (or any other language where June means the 6th month). Try `Sys.getlocale(category = "LC_ALL")` to be sure.

Comment: My locale says `[1] "en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF- 8/en_US.UTF-8"` @RHA However I am getting NA for the months such as "June", "May", etc.

Comment: Thanks @RHA! Is this because of the trailing space? @S.Galleg, Does replacing the second line with `Date2 = as.Date(paste0("01-",date,"-2013"), format = "%d-%B -%Y"),` work?

Comment: Note the space after `%B ` seeing as your strings are formatted like `June `, so when you paste them to `-2013` it looks like `June -2013` not `June-2013`.

Comment: @Jim Wouldn't it be better to remove these spaces with `trim`?

Comment: I see, I will try that. Thank you.

Comment: @S.Galleg - let me know how it goes. RHA - Same result!

Comment: That did not work for me, still got <NA>. I figured out a way to do it with a for loop. Thank you both for your help @RHA

Answer (score 0):

The answer is you should not, even if there is another column that tells you what the format it

How would you interpres 06/08/2010 
1) June the 8th 2010
2) Aug the 6th 2010

I would always convert to standard format so I could do calculations on that and then store. If I have to always display it different way then I would have another column that tells me how to display it.

Comment: I can display it in a new column but the question still remains how do I convert "June" to YYYY-MM-DD format?

Comment: What year would you use when year is not given?

Comment: 2013 for the year and the date can be 01